# OpenVPN server to access all server via IP Private from local

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, iptables, nat

I have 22 servers, where all servers have IP Private 192.168.0.0/24.

I installed OpenVPN on ubuntu server, I want to access all server via IP Private `192.168.0.0/24` from my local laptop.

On the OpenVPN server, `eth0` has an IP Public `183.121.31.42` and `eth1` has an IP private `192.168.0.5`.

I have run this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But I still can't connect to all of my servers via IP Private.

Comment: where did 10.8.0.0/24 come from? is that your OVPN tunnel network?

Comment: Yes, 10.8.0.0/24 its my OVPN tunnel network @FrankThomas

Comment: Could you help me please ? @FrankThomas

Comment: It is marginal if enough information has been provided for us to help you yet.  You say you have 22 servers on a /24, but is OpenVPN running on the router? Has that ubuntu Box been set up as a router (ie to forward packets)?  Are you routing 192.168.0.0/24 down the tunnel?  (ie what does your VPN clients route table look like?)

Comment: Does the openVPN connection terminate on this box? if so, I think you should put the rule on the OpenVPN intereface and drop the source address specification. so `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <OpenVPN Interface>  -j MASQUERADE`